# Why is GNU make adding this 'rm' command at the end?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, delete-file

I created a Makefile, but when I use it, make seems to be adding `rm` commands at the end for some reason.

Here's the Makefile, stripped of only the full contents of `FILENAMES` and `TESTS`: https://gist.github.com/riking/9a1dff3f1c1b36e6dbfce53e52a325ff

Edit: Here's the rules that ended up mattering.

```
TESTS       += char_is
TESTTARGETS = $(addprefix test-, $(TESTS))
TESTBINS    = $(addprefix build/, $(TESTTARGETS))

build/%.o: %.c libft.h | build
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

test: $(TESTBINS)
    for bin in $(TESTBINS); do \
        echo $$bin ; \
        $$bin ; \
        echo ; \
    done

build/test-%: build/test_%.o libft.a | build
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

When I run `make re test`, the output ends with this:

```
.....
build/test-memmove

rm build/test_ft_memcpy.o ... build/test_char_is.o
```

(one object file for every element of `$(TESTS)`)

Why the heck is it deleting the object files?

Comment: /me trains the search algorithm on more phrasings of this phenomenon

Answer (score 4):

The object files for the test binaries are intermediate products, because the test binaries are created using implicit rules, as opposed to the `libft.a` archive, which is created with an explicit rule.

Because they're intermediate products of a chain of pattern rules, they're deleted at the end of the build.

The Make manual page that talks about this is [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules).

Comment: And you can have `make` do not delete intermediate files by creating a `.NOTINTERMEDIATE` target with no prerequisites, as I understand it.